Extracting a std::unique_ptr member using std::move(), from a class that is invalid when null: how to avoid invisibly making object invalid?
Consider the following scenario.
We have a class bar that owns a foo data object via a unique pointer. A bar must always be constructible into a valid state; that is, bar must always own some data, so data should never be null. We can call get_data() to peer into the data of bar, but the ownership of this data should not change for as long as bar is alive. So, data is added to bar when we construct it: the constructor takes in the unique pointer via move semantics.
Then we have baz, which can own multiple foo data. We can add each data one at a time by using add_data(), using std::move() to move the data into baz. So far, so good.
struct foo {};

class bar
{
public:
    bar(std::unique_ptr<foo> data) : data{ std::move(data) }
    {
        if (!this->data)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{ "Unexpected null pointer" };
        }
    }

    foo* get_data() { return (this->data).get(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<foo> data;
};

class baz
{
public:
    baz() = default;

    void add_data(std::unique_ptr<foo> data) { vec.push_back(std::move(data)); }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> vec;
};

int main()
{
    // bar invalid_bar{ std::unique_ptr<foo>() }; // throws an exception

    std::unique_ptr<foo> data_0{ std::make_unique<foo>() };
    bar bar_0{ std::move(data_0) };

    std::unique_ptr<foo> data_1{ std::make_unique<foo>() };
    std::unique_ptr<foo> data_2{ std::make_unique<foo>() };
    std::unique_ptr<foo> data_3{ std::make_unique<foo>() };
    baz baz_0;
    baz_0.add_data(std::move(data_1));
    baz_0.add_data(std::move(data_2));
    baz_0.add_data(std::move(data_3));
}

Now I want to be able to merge the data in bar into that of baz:
void merge_data(baz& target, bar&& source)
{
    // ...
}

Contrary to the provided example code, these classes may instead represent large data structures, in which case unnecessary copying would best be avoid. The intention for this function is to take in a bar by move semantics, and whatever data was stored on it is now transferred to baz.
The problem is, this requires extracting the data from bar, along with its ownership. This means leaving a bar in an invalid null state. This extraction is fine if it happens inside merge_data(), since the bar is moved in, so the resulting invalid bar shouldn't see the light of day. However, extracting this data will involve adding a member function which is accesible to merge_data(). So, I consider adding the following public member to bar:
std::unique_ptr<foo> extract_data() { return std::move(this->data); }

This is ok, but there is one problem with this: since this is public, this means that there is a risk it could be called in the middle of the lifetime of a foo, risking the possibility of having foo in an invalid null state in the middle of use. I might be aware that calling this function will leave an invalid bar, and keep in mind to simply not use the bar after doing so. But I suspect it will be an unfortunate surprise to other uses who see the function and think that the extracted data is only being copied from bar!
How can I allow this extract_data() operation while avoiding leaving unsuspecting invalid bar objects?

"bar must always own some data so data should never be null"  - But that's not what bar does now. It'll gladly accept an empty unique_ptr

@TedLyngmo That's a good point, I completely missed that. In which case, I want the constructor to throw an exception if it catches a nullptr.

Do you consider a "moved-from" bar invalid or not? When you move bar inside the merge function, you can still use it afterwards, but you seem to be fine with that.

@fdan I consider it here to be invalid; it doesn't uphold the invariant of the class, where it holds a non-null unique pointer. There isn't a way I'm aware of preventing use of a moved-from object. Still, the fact it has been moved from should suggest to the user "this is in an unspecified state"; at that point, it is their risk regarding whether to use the moved-from or not.

According to your answer in the comments, whether moving bar leaves it in a valid state:

I consider it here to be invalid; it doesn't uphold the invariant of the class, where it holds a non-null unique pointer. [...] Still, the fact it has been moved from should suggest to the user "this is in an unspecified state"

You can simply add the ref-value qualifier && to extract_data:
std::unique_ptr<foo> extract_data() && { return std::move(this->data); }
This way, extract_data can only be called on rvalues of bar.
bar bar_0{std::make_unique<foo>()};

// does not compile, user may be tempted to use bar afterwards
bar_0.extract_data();

// compiles, user has to move bar first, unspecified state afterwards
std::move(bar_0).extract_data(); 


One approach is to make it a private member, and add merge_data() as a friend. This isn't perhaps the most ideal approach from a manageability point of view, especially if there are other classes I want to be merging data to; I would need to add a friend declaration for each use case.
Considering that extract_data() should only be called if there is no chance of leaving an invalid bar lying around, one approach I've tried is to use a rvalue-ref-qualifier so that extract_data() can only be called if bar is an rvalue. So, for a complete example:
struct foo {};

class bar
{
public:
    bar(std::unique_ptr<foo> data) : data{ std::move(data) }
    {
        if (!this->data)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{ "Unexpected null pointer" };
        }
    }

    foo* get_data() { return (this->data).get(); }
    std::unique_ptr<foo> extract_data() && { return std::move(this->data); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<foo> data;
};

class baz
{
public:
    baz() = default;

    void add_data(std::unique_ptr<foo> data) { vec.push_back(std::move(data)); }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> vec;
};

void merge_data(baz& target, bar&& source)
{
    target.add_data(std::move(source).extract_data());
}

int main()
{
    // bar invalid_bar{ std::unique_ptr<foo>() }; // throws an exception

    bar bar_0{ std::make_unique<foo>() };

    baz baz_0;
    merge_data(baz_0, std::move(bar_0));

    bar bar_1{ std::make_unique<foo>() };
    std::unique_ptr<foo> extracted{ std::move(bar_1).extract_data() };
}

This way, any time the data is extracted from bar, the user must use std::move() on any lvalue references of bar. I realise that this doesn't really fix the issue of preventing invalid bar from existing: bar_1 is likely to be invalid after the move. But that's always going to be the case when dealing with std::move(). Since we are forced to use std::move() on any lvalue bar we want to extract the data from, it is explicitly signified to the user that all bets are off for any usage of bar after the matter.
